# How do I add a ProgressBar and then display a remote ImageView in a ListView?

Tags: android, image, listview, android-listview, android-drawable

I have a ListView of receipt data, which includes a vendor, value of the receipt, and the date on the receipt.

I'd like to add an lazy-loaded image of the receipt to my ListView. I have thumbnail images of the receipt stored in an AWS location, but the receipt images could be 'processing' and not immediately available. Unfortunately, the URL for the remote image is not available in my current ListView dataset, which means I have to call an async task to retrieve the receipt image data for each displayed row in my adapter.

To get the receipt image data, I have created a service call (I'm using Retrofit) to hit my API to pull down the JsonObject that contains the receipt image thumbnail location OR an indication that the image is still processing/not available. The receipt image data is requested via a receipt id.

Here's what I currently have:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ReceiptHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ReceiptHolder();
            holder.txtVendor = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.vendor_field);
            holder.txtAmount = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.amount_field);
            holder.txtDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.date_field);                           

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ReceiptHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        Receipts r = data[position];
        String fullValue = r.amount_symbol + r.amount;
        holder.txtVendor.setText(r.vendor);
        holder.txtAmount.setText(fullValue);
        holder.txtDate.setText(r.date);

        return row;
    }

    public class ReceiptHolder {
        public TextView txtVendor;
        public TextView txtAmount;
        public TextView txtDate;
        public ProgressBar receiptFetch;
        public ImageView receiptThumb;
    }
```

So, when my custom adapter is performing the getView, I'd like the following to happen:

1. The ProgressBar receiptFetch to be set as visible on initial draw to indicate that the image is still being retrieved/processed. I'd like the receipt data to be visible and a ProgressBar indicating that the image is still being retrieved or processed.
2. Some kind of non-blocking mechanism to go back and set ProgressBar's visibility to GONE and simultaneously setting ImageView receiptThumb with the asynchronously retrieved URL for *each* **row** item as the task completes for that particular **row**.

Now, here's my question:

How do I get the View holder pattern to play nice without hanging up the UX? Ideally when the adapter is doing its thing, I could kick off an async task to retrieve the receipt image data for each receipt while populating the other fields inherent to receipt data... but I'm not sure how to capture the response to turn off the ProgressBar and go back to populate the ImageView.

I've been unsuccessfully dabbling at this for a bit, and I'm stumped. Does my question make sense? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Picasso is the answer.

Universal Image Loader would also work, but was simply overkill for the problem I was trying to solve. Picasso does inline lazy loading, and has options to allow for a temporary @Drawable to be shown while the thumbnail is retrieved.

I ended up doing the following - didn't need the ProgresBar anymore since Picasso took care of it. Note that Picasso can be used in a static way - but I had to create a custom OkHttpClient for our networking configuration :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ReceiptHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                    .getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ReceiptHolder();
            holder.txtVendor = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.vendor_field);
            holder.txtAmount = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.amount_field);
            holder.txtDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.date_field);              
            holder.receiptThumb = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.receipt_image);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ReceiptHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Receipts r = data[position];
        String fullValue = r.amount_symbol + r.amount;
        holder.txtVendor.setText(r.vendor);
        holder.txtAmount.setText(fullValue);
        holder.txtDate.setText(r.date);     

        picasso.with(getActivity())             
            .load(r.medium_jpg_url)             
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .resize(100, 100)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.receiptThumb);

        return row;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UniversalImageLoader library to load your remote image.

```
Refer this: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

final View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
final ImageView imageView = ...

imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```